# Crash application when upload file >256 Mb in iOs (Córdova 3.5.0 FilTransfer 0.4.4)

Tags: ios, file-transfer, cordova-3

When uploading a file >256MB on iPad an error occurs, the application closes. 
The application is built on the Cordova 3.5.0

- Cordova 3.5.0
- File 1.2.0
- FileTransfer 0.4.4
- iPad 2 version 7.1.2

**Code function upload:**

function uploadVideo(task_id) {

```
 navigator.camera.getPicture(
    successGetFileFromCamera,
    failGetFileFromCamera,
    {
       quality: 100,
       destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
       sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
       mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.VIDEO
    }
 );

var chargeBar = '';

function successGetFileFromCamera(fileURI) {
    console.log('Success Camera method getPicture. ' + fileURI);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI, successGetFileFromLocal, failGetFileFromLocal);
}

function successGetFileFromLocal(fileEntry) {
    console.log('Success object LocalFileSystem method resolveLocalFileSystemURL.');
    console.log(fileEntry);
    fileEntry.file(successFile, failFile);
}

function successFile(fileObj) {
    console.log('Success File method file.');
    console.log(fileObj);

    var localURL = fileObj.localURL,
        fileName = fileObj.name;

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "my_video";
    options.fileName = fileName;
    options.mimeType="video/mp4";
    var params = {};
    params.task_id = task_id;
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    ft.upload(localURL, encodeURI(host + '/myserver/uploadFile/projectId:' + projectId + '/responderId:' + responderId), successUploadFileToServ, failUploadFileToServ, options);
}

function successUploadFileToServ(r) {
    console.log('Success FileTransfer method upload.');
    console.log(r);
    closeProgress();
    data = $.parseJSON(r.response);
    $.mobile.changePage('index.html');
    if(data.result) {
        navigator.notification.alert('Video file has been successfully loaded', null, 'Upload file', null);
    } else {
        dataHaveError(data);
    }
}
```

}

**Log devvice**

Sep  4 11:52:18 iPad-Sergej MyApp[1364] : Success Camera method getPicture. file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/8DC19A51-BB7E-45BB-88B2-E12445F1EB99/tmp/trim.EDD77556-5D40-4009-9A50-BB67D6145727.MOV
Sep  4 11:52:18 iPad-Sergej MyApp[1364] : THREAD WARNING: ['File'] took '15.891846' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Sep  4 11:52:18 iPad-Sergej MyApp[1364] : Success object LocalFileSystem method resolveLocalFileSystemURL.
Sep  4 11:52:18 iPad-Sergej MyApp[1364] : {"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"trim.EDD77556-5D40-4009-9A50-BB67D6145727.MOV","fullPath":"/trim.EDD77556-5D40-4009-9A50-BB67D6145727.MOV","filesystem":"","nativeURL":"file:///var/mobile/Applications/8DC19A51-BB7E-45BB-88B2-E12445F1EB99/tmp/trim.EDD77556-5D40-4009-9A50-BB67D6145727.MOV"}
Sep  4 11:52:18 iPad-Sergej MyApp[1364] : THREAD WARNING: ['File'] took '69.734131' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Sep  4 11:52:18 iPad-Sergej MyApp[1364] : Success File method file.
Sep  4 11:52:18 iPad-Sergej MyApp[1364] : {"name":"trim.EDD77556-5D40-4009-9A50-BB67D6145727.MOV","localURL":"cdvfile://localhost/temporary/trim.EDD77556-5D40-4009-9A50-BB67D6145727.MOV","type":null,"lastModifiedDate":1409817138000,"size":408288782,"start":0,"end":408288782}
Sep  4 11:52:18 iPad-Sergej MyApp[1364] : MyApp(1364,0x3a76618c) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=408289280) failed (error code=3)**
 error: can't allocate region
 **set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Sep  4 11:52:18 iPad-Sergej MyApp[1364] :**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSFileHandleOperationException', reason: ' **-[NSConcreteFileHandle readDataOfLength:]: Cannot allocate memory'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2d6f8f83 0x381dfccf 0x2d6f8ec5 0x2e0a7931 0x2e0a7fe3 0xe4aff 0xe76a5 0xd2849 0xd253f 0x2e0d9163 0x2d6c4167 0x2d6c3d7f 0x2d6c211b 0x2d62cebf 0x2d62cca3 0x32527663 0x2ff7914d 0xd5af7 0x386ecab7)
Sep  4 11:52:18 iPad-Sergej ReportCrash[1365] : ReportCrash acting against PID 1364
Sep  4 11:52:19 iPad-Sergej ReportCrash[1365] : Formulating crash report for process MyApp[1364]
Sep  4 11:52:19 iPad-Sergej mediaserverd[1160] : 11:52:19.667 [0x2212000] CMSession retain count > 1!
Sep  4 11:52:19 iPad-Sergej SpringBoard[33] : [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Sep  4 11:52:19 iPad-Sergej com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.my_app[0x51e5][1364]) : (UIKitApplication:com.my_app[0x51e5]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Sep  4 11:52:19 iPad-Sergej backboardd[29] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.my_app[0x51e5]' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
Sep  4 11:52:19 iPad-Sergej ReportCrash[1365] : Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MyApp_2014-09-04-115218_iPad-Sergej.ips using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0

***Can anyone faced a similar problem please help. Or need to use another plugin upload.***

Comment: Did you do what the message said and add a breakpoint in `malloc_error_break`?